# decrypt *.bin file in C using openssl

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

i've got a question for my study stuff: I have to decrypt a file(src-cipher.bin) using C. I have a corrupt key corrupt-src-key.bin (an initial vector is at the end of the file - dont know if i should this vector- maybe dont have to). final decrypted file should be a *.pdf one and it was encrypted with Camellia-192-OFB (openssl EVP_camellia_192_ofb() ). Byte number 23(start counting from 0) was set to 0. Now i have to write a small C app which decrypts this file. At least ive got 2 more files(src-cipher.bin and dest-key.bin)). Thanks very much for help. If someone is interested, i can send the files. Thx

Comment: So what is the question though?

Comment: i do not know what i have to do. can i use standard openssl lib even with the corrupt key?

Comment: You need to read your course material and ask your professor/TA if there's anything unclear. We can't do that for you. If you know which byte is corrupt, you can brute force that byte, that is, try all values from 0 to 255 or until decryption succeeds. This is what I can guess based on your description.

Comment: ok, but can i get an example command using openSSL and camellia_192_ofb for decrypt the file like: "openssl camellia-192-ofb -decrypt -in src-cipher.bin -out plain.pdf -linkey corrupt-src-key.bin"? if the key would be ok? thanks

Comment: I have no idea what your school wants you to do, I haven't read your syllabus. No, the example command won't work with a corrupt key. Judging by your words, you need to write a C program that calls the OpenSSL function `EVP_camellia_192_ofb`. Perhaps you need to call this function many times, trying different values of the corrupt byte. It is hard to tell exactly without attending the same lectures and labs you have supposedly attended.

Comment: now i got the correct key, i set the zero byte to the right value, but do not know the right command in openSSL

Comment: You might find this useful. Its a gentle approach, and it gives you lots of examples in a scripting language. The book is also "challenge" based, so it presents problems and asks you to solve them before providing the answers. [Hacking Secret Ciphers with Python: A beginner's guide to cryptography and computer programming with Python](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1482614375).